# ParentId on EmailMessage is not writable?

Tags: email2case, emailmessage

We have a business scenario where an incoming `EmailMessage` sent to a closed Case, should be automatically reparented to another case that's Opened.

The logic would achieve this by modifying the `ParentId` field in the `EmailMessage` instance.

The logic was in place since January 18'. Suddenly, since this morning we're getting errors like this one:

> CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY : EmailMessageTrigger: execution of AfterInsert
>   caused by: System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: EmailMessage.ParentId

In the Workbench this field, does appear to have the updateable attribute set to false.

Has this behaviour changed "overnight" from Salesforce and we suddenly cannot reparent the `EmailMessage` instances in Salesforce?

Comment: v46 doc says ParentId is not updateable. did a version change for you in the apex class that did the reparenting?

Comment: The class where the error happens is V45.0. Whereas the Org API version is V46.0(obviously I guess, as this corresponds with the summer release 19').